# Create a list of types and access a static member of each type?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a number of child classes which all have a static `type_id` field. What I am trying to do is save a list of types (which from searching around, I know that's a touchy subject) and then access the `type_id` of the types in my type list. Here's an example

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

struct base_type
{
    static const uint64_t type_id = 0;
};

struct A : public base_type
{
    static const uint64_t type_id = 1;
};

struct B : public base_type
{
    static const uint64_t type_id = 2;
};

struct C : public base_type
{
    static const uint64_t type_id = 3;
};


template <class... Args>
struct type_list
{
    template <std::size_t N>
    using type = typename std::tuple_element<N, std::tuple<Args...>>::type;
};

int main()
{
  using my_types = type_list<base_type, A, B, C>;
  std::cout << my_types::type<1>.type_id << std::endl;
}
```

And then hopefully that would print out 1. However, if you try to compile this it won't work. Is there any way to achieve something like this?

---

Edit: The solution was so simple I'm ashamed. Just needed `my_types::type<1>::type_id` instead of `my_types::type<1>.type_id`

Comment: Please add the error message to the question

Answer (score 4):

Access of static member from type uses `::` not `.`:

```
my_types::type<1>::type_id
```

Comment: Well duh, made it 90% of the way there and then fell on my face